# Weather Logger Not Working?

Tags: raspbian, python

When I run my code for my sense hat weather station it outputs the error:

```
File "/home/pi/weather_script.py", line 17
   humidity = sense.get_humidity()
   ^

IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import time
import sys
from ISStreamer.Streamer import Streamer  

sense = SenseHat()
logger = Streamer(bucket_name="Sense Hat Sensor Data", access_key="MY_ACCESS_KEY")  
sense.clear()

try:
      while True:
           temp = sense.get_temperature()
           temp = 1.8 * round(temp, 1) + 32
           logger.log("Temperature F",temp) 

            humidity = sense.get_humidity()  
            humidity = round(humidity, 1)  
            logger.log("Humidity :",humidity)  

            pressure = sense.get_pressure()
            pressure = round(pressure, 1)
            logger.log("Pressure:",pressure)

           time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
      pass
```

I replaced my access key with MY_ACCESS_KEY. Please help.

Comment: It is exactly what it claims to be, an indentation error. Why do you increase indentation of those six lines by one whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ghanima points out you have added superfluous white space.  Python requires correct spacing to determine the meaning of a script.

Remove one space character at the start of the following lines.

```
    humidity = sense.get_humidity()  
    humidity = round(humidity, 1)  
    logger.log("Humidity :",humidity)  

    pressure = sense.get_pressure()
    pressure = round(pressure, 1)
    logger.log("Pressure:",pressure)
```